# Information document with secure protocol in wsdl

Tags: java, https, wsdl

File **APPWSImpl.java**

```
@WebService(serviceName = APPWSService", portName = "APPWSPort", targetNamespace = "http://webservice.app.com/", endpointInterface = "com.app.webservice.APPWS")
@HandlerChain(file = "handlers.xml")
public class APPWSImpl implements APPWS {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(APPWSImpl.class);

    @Resource
    WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

    @Override
    public APPResponse handleRequest(APPRequest request) {
        return handleRequest(request, APPUtil.getRemoteHost(webServiceContext));
    }

    private APPResponse handleRequest(APPRequest request, String remoteHost) {
        return APPHandler.handleRequest(request, remoteHost);
    }

        @Override
    public ReadCalendarsResponse readCalendars(ReadCalendarsRequest request) {
        return (ReadCalendarsResponse) APPHandlerUtil.handleStaticRequest(request,
                APPUtil.getRemoteHost(webServiceContext));
    }

}
```

File **APPWS.java**

```
 @WebService
public interface APPWS {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "return")
    public APPResponse handleRequest(APPRequest request);

    @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
    @WebResult(name = "readCalendarsResponse")
    public ReadCalendarsResponse readCalendars(ReadCalendarsRequest request);

    

}
```

File **binding.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    wsdlLocation="../wsdl/APPWSService.wsdl" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/jaxws/wsdl_customizationschema_2_0.xsd">

    <enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>

    <bindings node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType[@name='APPWS']/wsdl:operation[@name='handleRequest']">
        <enableWrapperStyle>true</enableWrapperStyle>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

File **APPWSService.wsdl**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.9-b14002 svn-revision#14004. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest/APPWSService.wsdl" name="APPWSService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:tns="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest/APPWSService.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest/APPWSService.wsdl" schemaLocation="APPWSService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="readCalendars">
    <part name="readCalendars" element="tns:readCalendars"/>
  </message>
  <message name="readCalendarsResponse">
    <part name="readCalendarsResponse" element="tns:readCalendarsResponse"/>
  </message>

  <portType name="APPWS">
    <operation name="readCalendars">
      <input wsam:Action="https://webservice.APP.com/APPWS/readCalendarsRequest" message="tns:readCalendars"/>
      <output wsam:Action="https://webservice.APP.com/APPWS/readCalendarsResponse" message="tns:readCalendarsResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="APPWSPortBinding" type="tns:APPWS">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="readCalendars">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="APPWSService">
    <port name="APPWSPort" binding="tns:APPWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

File **APPWSService_schema1.xsd**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest/APPWSService.wsdl" xmlns:tns="https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest/APPWSService.wsdl" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="readCalendars" nillable="true" type="tns:readCalendarsRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="readCalendarsResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:readCalendarsResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="readCalendarsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="credentials" type="tns:credentials"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="readCalendarsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="responseStatus" type="tns:responseStatus"/>
      <xs:element name="calendar" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The client services have been created from wsdl and xsd with Maven.

File **pom.xml**

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-wsdl-client-APPWSService</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/jaxws</bindingDirectory>
                <wsdlDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles> 
                    <wsdlFile>APPWSService.wsdl</wsdlFile> 
                </wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlLocation>APPWSService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                <packageName>com.app.ws.client</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
</plugin>
```

If I load the wsdl in SOAPUI, the https actions respond correctly. What it does not believe well is the wsdl information document when requested by the secure protocol `https://dominio.dev.corp/APPWebService/HandleRequest?wsdl`. It always appears as http and the service block is as follows:

```
  <service name="APPWSService">
    <port name="APPWSPort" binding="tns:APPWSPortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://dominio.dev.corp:80/APPWebService/HandleRequest"/>
    </port>
  </service>
```

What I need is the wsdl with the location property, `\<soap:address location=`, the url with the secure protocol. This way anyone can call the information document and load it into SOAPUI without modifying anything.

Has anything like this happened to anyone?

Thank you very much in advance.